# invalid arguments

Tags: asp.net, linq

for Retrieving the File from Database i have used below linq query for downloading efile , but i have problem invalid arguments in function download(Efile).
i have seen some where use datatable for downloading. i liked to do that without use datatable but i do not know how?

```
the fields of table tblfile is like below.

fileid(int), FileName (varchar(50)), ContentType (varchar(50)), Data varbinary(MAX)
```

please help what is the problem.

```
protected void LinkButton1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Download")
    {
       _DataContext = new EDMSDataContext();
       //you can get your command argument values as follows
       string FileId = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
       int _FileId = Convert.ToInt32(FileId);
       var Efile = from ef in _DataContext.tblFiles
                   where ef.FileId == _FileId
                   select ef;
       if (Efile != null)
       {
           download(Efile);
       }
    }
}

private void download ( tblFile Efile)
{
    Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])Efile.Data.ToArray();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = Efile.ContentType.ToString();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename="
        + Efile.FileName.ToString());
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method is accepting the argument of "tblFile" object and you are passing the collection. Add the Single() to your linq query expression and it get resolved.

```
   var Efile = (from ef in _DataContext.tblFiles
               where ef.FileId == _FileId
               select ef).Single();
```

Alternately, you could use `First()`, `FirstOrDefault()` or `SingleOrDefault()` as well.

Comment: thanks error removed but it seems download function does not work and no downloading happen

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your .dbml file has a property of your table **tblfile** properly as you want and as you described here. and use below code for retrying data from database.

```
tblFile data = _DataContext.tblFile.SingleOrDefault(s=>s.fileid  ==  _FileId);
```

This will work as you want.